# JSTL in IntelliJ gives errors in JSP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jstl

I'm playing with Google App Engine in IntelliJ. I'm trying to use JSTL tags in my JSPs. I've tried two different URIs I found on the internet, and both of them give me errors:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

and

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

It reds out the URL and says it cannot resolve taglib. I've tried dropping different parts of the URL to see if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> gives me any autocomplete love, but no luck.

Any ideas what I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What IDEA version do you use? IDEA 10.5.1 should handle it fine, but there was a problem with IDEA 10.0.3. We also have similar bug report for 10.5, but we are not able to reproduce it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-69942. Try to reinstall IDEA 10.5.1 or 10.5.2 from http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+10.5+EAP.

Comment: I'm on 10.5.1 (June 29, 2011). Could it be because I don't have the J2EE sdk installed on my machine? It never occurred to me as the problem since IntelliJ usually auto-downloads any jars for built-in support.

Comment: You need JSTL libraries downloaded and added to the module dependencies: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: yeah, I feel silly now. If you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure that JSTL library jars are added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html).

Answer (score 14):

Add something like this to your `pom.xml` under the `<dependencies>` node (you are using maven, right?):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

For gradle and other build systems see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5

Also, make sure you pick a suitable version for your project. To see all available versions check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api).

Comment: <version>1.2</version>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to download the .jar from apache (https://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/) and add to my project dependencies.

```
File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding `jstl-1.2` in the libraries.

- Right-click on "project"
- Then go into "open modules setting"
- Then in "libraries" click on the "+", then "add with maven"
- Click on the checkbox to download in a folder, change the folder path for `.../WEB-INF/lib` (create the `lib` folder)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

For using JSTL tags in IntelliJ IDEA Community and Ultimate editions, we need to add `jstl` and `jstl-api` dependencies.

If you are using Tomcat 10.1.12:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If your are using Tomcat 9:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And don't forget to add taglib directive on top of the jsp page before restarting the IDE:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```