# Java Google App Engine with IntelliJ: Cannot Resolve taglib with uri "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jstl

I have experience with Google App Engine in Eclipse so I thought I would try IntelliJ for app development as well to see which I like better.  I have the project using the app engine sdk I just cant seem to get it to find the JSTL jar.  I know in eclipse it did this automatically without me having to manually import the JSTL jars is there a way to do this in Intellij? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think eclipse imports automatically. You must copy JSTL jars into some folder [may be lib] and then need to add them in build path. I think the same will be applied in any editor. For downloading jars you can see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292914/where-can-i-download-jstl-jar

Comment: I have the jars in the tools folder in the app engine SDK.  In eclipse I download the plugin and out of the box jstl works.  Would this just be the plugin auto including the jars? How do I see which app engine jars specifically are used in eclipse so I can use the same ones in intellij? Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: This post might help you -

[JSTL in IntelliJ gives errors in JSP][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253034/jstl-in-intellij-gives-errors-in-jsp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043869/intellij-and-jsp-jstl-cannot-resolve-taglib-for-jstl-in-tomcat7/32444393#32444393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the tags are working the editor just isn't showing it inside the editor, thanks!